# How to convert a voice recorded by AVAudioRecorder into Text in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, avaudiorecorder

I am working on a project where I have to record a voice covert into text then match the pattern and according to the user command perform action.

I am able to to record voice of the user through AVAudioRecorder and perform action. But the actions are perform on anything what user says. I want to perform on user's particular word like if he say play then playing should start.

Help me by any tutorial or any sample code.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Other than the below mentioned OpenEars and VocalKit is there any other way to achieve this. Me too trying to retrieve the text details with AVAudioRecorder but no solutions yet. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most apps (including Siri) send the sound file to a remote data center via to do the speech recognition, which involves some fairly heavy duty processing.  Nuance may have an commercial API.

Another option might be to try using the [CMU OpenEars](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/09/openears-speech-library-for-iphone-using-cmusphinx/) or PocketSphinx speech library, which has been ported to the iPhone.  Also look at [VocalKit](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/05/vocalkit-shim-for-speech-recognition-on-iphone/) and this article on running [PocketSphinx on the iPhone](http://www.rajeevan.co.uk/pocketsphinx_in_iphone/).

Comment: OpenEars is from Politepix; the CMU Pocketsphinx library is one of its dependencies. Pocketsphinx does have a configure script for iPad/iPhone that can create a compiled library that doesn't require OpenEars, while OpenEars bundles Pocketsphinx together with Flite TTS, dynamic language model generation and a remoteio audio driver/audio session wrapper that can do handsfree continuous recognition, as a cross-project-referenced static library (I'm the developer).